# How to make multiple .net projects copy references only one time in the build

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, build, msbuild

I have a solution with multiple MVC and libraries projects and the build of this solution is very slow.

To improve the build performance, I changed all projects to output in the same folder and changed all project references to copy local = false, this improved the build performance almost in 90%, from 10m to 1m30s.

However, this generated an issue, in run mode my application show errors because have no references assemblies in the output folder.

I'd like to know if exists a way, to make solution copy the references only one time to my output folder.

I tried somethings, like a target to copy the dlls from packages folder to the output folder, but this not work correctly, because in a packages folder can exists dlls from many framework versions.

Any ideia to solve this issue?

Comment: One of the projects should have all references and CopyLocal set to true, that is the easiest and the fastest. Any other solutions would also start slowing down the build, as they'd basically have to perform roughly the same logic as the built-in way of copying references.

Comment: @stijn thanks for you suggestion, I have been thought in something like it, however seems a little overkill. I'll leave this to last option, if I can not find another way.

Comment: I wanted to reproduce your issue to see what goes on, but I can't: when CopyLocal = True, the Copy step used for references actually won't copy the file if it didn't change (i.e. it just checks time stamps and the detailed msbuild log has entries like `Did not copy xxx because the "SkipUnchangedFiles" parameter was set to "true" in the project and the files' sizes and timestamps match`). So: you'll have to provide more information: with CopyLocal set to True and a common output directory, what is the problem? What is slow?

Comment: @stijn The performance issue is in the first build, to the next build the performance is better. However, in my build server we always empty the folders before build to not have any issue.

Comment: And that is with CopyLocal True and a common output directory? If you run this with detailed logging do you get similar output as mentioned above? Or are files copied multiple times?

Comment: Using copy local = true, some files are copied multiple times and others showing the message that you mentioned above.

Comment: @stijn I searched some ideas, I didn't found a better idea than create a project with the references, so I used what you said above. If want, put this comment like an answer that I'll mark this as best answer. Thank you

Comment: It would be interesting to find out why certain files are copied more than once, that should by default not happen, but unless you can spot an immediate difference, it is going to be hard to figure out why for anybody else here without seeing what files (would require you posting relevant parts of the build log) and possibly the entire project structure: there can be a couple of reasons for that. It can maybe be resolved by overriding the _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal Target which copies the files and forcing the copy to only take place if the destination file is different. I'll add that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common solution is to have all projects output to the same directory, and have all references set to CopyLocal=False, and then have one extra project (or an existing one, like the main application) targetting the same output directory and which contains *all* references and has CopyLocal=True. Then that one project effectively takes care of getting all your references where you want them. To get all projects use the same output directory I'd suggest to modify the .csproj files to all import the same file which sets the OutputPath property instead of manually changing it in each project.

Alternatively, since you mention the main problem with a single output directory and CopyLocal set to True is that some files get copied multiple times, you could modify how the copying occurs. Normally, by default, the Copy tasks used will skip files with matching timestamps. This is controlled by the SkipCopyUnchangedFiles flag so you could force it to true and see if that changes anything:

```
msbuild my.sln /p:SkipCopyUnchangedFiles=True
```

Or you could even ask it to use hardlinks instead of copying, this should effectively mean no copies are made at all:

```
msbuild my.sln /p:CreateHardLinksForCopyLocalIfPossible=True
```

or symbolic links:

```
msbuild my.sln /p:CreateSymbolicLinksForCopyLocalIfPossible=True
```

If all else fails and files are still copied more than once it could mean e.g. that one project references A.dll and another one also references A.dll but from a different directory or a different version etc, so it will get copied twice no matter what unless you fix that.